# hash_djb2 PHP result is wrong?

Tags: php, c++

C++

```
unsigned int hash_djb2(char *str, unsigned int str_size)
{
    unsigned int hash = 5381;

    for(unsigned int c = 0; c < str_size; c++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + str[c];

    return (hash & 0xFFFFFFFF);
}

int main()
{
    string term = "one piece";
    char* data = const_cast<char*>(term.c_str());
    printf("%u", hash_djb2(data, term.size()));//2850035213
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
    function hash_djb2($str)
    {
        $hash = 5381;
        $length = strlen($str);
        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $hash = ( ($hash << 5) + $hash ) + $str[$i];
        }
        return ($hash & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    }

    echo hash_djb2("one piece");//-233010523
?>
```

How to make PHP return the same result as C++ does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str[c]` in PHP is the problem, because addition with it tries to parse
the string content as a number, ie. "123"=>123 and "O", "n" etc. becomes simply 0.
Use `ord(str[c])` to get ASCII values.

Additionally, int casts and more `&0xFFFFFFFF` are probably a good idea,
else PHP can/will switch to double with larger values.

Comment: Now I am getting `-1444932083`

Comment: That´s the right value, only different signed-ness. Ie. `2^32 - 1444932083 = 2850035213`. Use signed instead of unsigned in C++ to get the same value. (There is no unsigned in PHP, so C++ has to adapt)

Comment: Okay, I see, thanks. Is there a way to use unsigned in C++ and do this in PHP using BC?

Comment: I did it by replacing the last line with `return ($hash & 0xFFFFFFFF) + 0x80000000 + 0x80000000;` is there a drawback with this?

Comment: This just won´t work, only in special cases (32bit, some special php compilation flags etc.). Try a 64bit installation here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/